# Trying to get different background images to show based on screen resolution?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I am running into a problem. I am trying to load a different image based on the screen resolution but I tried the code listed below it doesn't load the background. I have a css and jquery setup when said and the background doesn't show. I don't know where I am going wrong?

```
@media (min-width:800px) { .w800 { background-image: url(images/DCBG800.png);                      @media (min-width:1024px) { .w1024 { background-image: url(images/DCBG1024.png);
@media (min-width:1152px) { .w1152 { background-image: url(images/DCBG1152.png);
@media (min-width:1280px) { .w1280 { background-image: url(images/DCBG1280.png);
@media (min-width:1360px) { .w1360 { background-image: url(images/DCBG1360.png);
@media (min-width:1366px) { .w1366 { background-image: url(images/DCBG1366.png);
@media (min-width:1600px) { .w1600 { background-image: url(images/DCBG1600.png);
}

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function setImageClass() {
switch(true) {
    case($(window).width()>1600): $("body").removeClass("w800 w1024 w1152 w1280 w1360 w1366").addClass("w1600");
    break;
    case($(window).width()>1366): $("body").removeClass("w800 w1024 w1152 w1280 w1360 w1600").addClass("w1366");
    break;
    case($(window).width()>1360): $("body").removeClass("w800 w1024 w1152 w1280 w1366 w1600").addClass("w1360");
    break;
    case($(window).width()>1280): $("body").removeClass("w800 w1024 w1152 w1360 w1366 w1600").addClass("w1280");
    break;
    case($(window).width()>1152): $("body").removeClass("w800 w1024 w1280 w1360 w1366 w1600").addClass("w1152");
    break;
    case($(window).width()>1024): $("body").removeClass("w800 w1152 w1280 w1360 w1366 w1600").addClass("w600");
    break;
    default: $("body").removeClass("w1024 w1152 w1280 w1360 w1366 w1600").addClass("w800");
    break;
}
   }

    $(document).ready(function() {
setImageClass();
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
setImageClass();
    });
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `@media all and (min-width ...`

Comment: It also looks rather redundant - you should rely on the media queries to work and drop all that "add/removeClass" stuff. Your CSS selector would then need to change from .wXXX to body.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I was surprised myself, but according to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ (Example 5), both options are valid - with or without `"all and"`

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing any of your curly brackets in the CSS Example. Further, try to get rid of all the classes on "body" (i.e. also of the javascript for now), and apply the background-image css rule directly to the "body" element selector, like this:

```
@media (min-width:800px) { 
   body {
       background-image: url(images/DCBG800.png); 
   }
}
```

I hope this helps,

Lukx

Comment: Thank you for the help!! Since I am using a jscript as a backup since IE doesn't like the '@media tag'. I'm just sure how many curly brackets I need, and when I only add one to each one it turns the '@media' tag black and not blue like the rest of the code.

Comment: That's rather simple: Generally, you need one closing curly bracket for each opening bracket. Did the syntax fix help you already?